# Client side of socket server throwing not an error that says operation attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am getting this error for the client part of a socket server that I am learning to make. I have searched for the error,  and found several articles but they do not seem to be related to my issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/prog0/client.py", line 13, in <module>
    socketRead, socketWrite, socketError = select.select(sockets, [], [])
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Can anyone help explain to me what could be the issue, because honestly have no idea. The client does connect to the server before this error occurs.

```
import select
import socket
import sys

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
IP_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 12000

server.connect((IP_ADDRESS, PORT))

while True:
    sockets = [sys.stdin, server]
    socketRead, socketWrite, socketError = select.select(sockets, [], [])

    for s in socketRead:
        if s == server:
            msg = s.recv(1024)
            print(msg)
        else:
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            server.send(msg)
            sys.stdout.write("<You>")
            sys.stdout.write(msg)
            sys.stdout.flush()

server.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on a *nix system, but you cannot use an ordinary file's descriptor in a `select` on windows: See the documentation note in https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/select.html:

> **Note** File objects on Windows are not acceptable, but sockets are. On Windows, the underlying `select()` function is provided by the WinSock library, and does not handle file descriptors that don’t originate from WinSock.